# Timeline of machine learning and data mining breakthroughs

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, history

Is there any timeline or historical overview of the most important breakthroughs in machine learning and data mining?

Answer (score 1):

This is far from complete, but Volker Tresp (Siemens) gives a nice timeline in the third slide of [this](http://www.sics.se/~aho/tor/Volker_Tresp_ToR-101125.pdf) talk.